# Ubuntu 20.04. How do I set up a virtual/dummy monitor so that I can use NoMachine without a monitor plugged in?

Tags: networking, 20.04, remote-access

I am running the NoMachine Client on my windows 10 desktop and my server on my Ubuntu machine. I want to use NoMachine to remote control this server but I can't unless a monitor is plugged in.

Comment: Have you consitered [getting a physical dummy plug](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi+dummy+plug)? That might work. Of course, get one for the correct display output your server has. Also, if you aren't too attached to NoMachine, other remote-access programs (like VNC or RDP) don't require a monitor, so consider using one of those instead.